# Exception in thread not be able to read values in constructors

Tags: java, exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length;

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

//import jdk.javadoc.internal.doclets.formats.html.SourceToHTMLConverter;

class checkMatrix1 {
    int row;
    int column;
    int[][] matrix = new int[row][column];

    public checkMatrix1(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }
    public checkMatrix1() {
        this.row = 3;
        this.column = 3;
    }
}

public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" Enter Row: ");
        System.out.println(" Enter Column: ");
        int row = input.nextInt();
        int column = input.nextInt();
        checkMatrix1 matrix1 = new checkMatrix1(row, column);

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.column; j++) {
                System.out.println(matrix1.matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not able to read values in the constructor from the user

Comment: on what line does that error occur? int[][] matrix = new int[row][column]; this isn't impacted by what you send to the constructor, so it's always empty. probably not what you want

Answer (score 5):

First the field initializers run, then the constructor runs. So, if you call, say, `new checkMatrix(2, 2);`

> `int row;`

row is now 0.

> `int column;`

column is now 0.

> `int[][] matrix = new int[row][column];`

matrix is now a 0 by 0 array.

Now we move on to the lines in the constructor..

> `this.row = row;`

> `this.column = column;`

row and colum are now 2. Too late for the `new int[][]` statement though.

Move the `new int[]` statement into the constructor, and rewrite your default constructor to `this(3, 3)` to avoid having to duplicate this code.